# Reading & Writing json to a file

Tags: php, api, object

I have a script that returns a PHP object.
The object looks like this:

```
OP_Reply Object ( [faultCode:protected] => 0 [faultString:protected] => [value:protected] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [domain] => google.nl [status] => active ) [1] => Array ( [domain] => google.com [status] => active ) ) [warnings:protected] => Array ( ) [raw:protected] => 0google.nlactivegoogle.comactive [maintenance:protected] => )
```

I tried iterating through it with a foreach() but that doesn't return me anything.
I want to get the `[status]` field for all the `[domain]`'s so I can execute some code using these values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the following library:

https://doc.openprovider.eu/index.php/Example_Class_API_PHP

You can access given elements through its methods. First you need to get value, then you can access elements within that array:

```
$value = $obj->getValue();
$status = $value[0]['status'];
$domain = $value[0]['domain'];
```

(there are multiple values in $value array, so I specified the first element = index zero)

Comment: Ok, I can now get the domain name and status for the first (0) domain in the object, but how can I get it for all of them? I tried a for loop but I don't know the length.

Comment: You can use `foreach ($value as $row)` to iterate over the array with unknown length

Comment: I got this `foreach($domains as $key => $value) {
 $status = $key[0];
 print_r($status);
}` now but it shows me an empty screen.

Comment: After getting `$values = $obj->getValue();` you can try to `print_r` it directly: `print_r($values);` This should display array structure, so that you can iterate

Comment: Ok now I have `foreach($domains as $key) {
 foreach($key as $key2 => $value) {
  print_r($value);
 }
}` but that prints me the domain and status seperately. All I need is to perform some code for every domain once not twice.

Comment: Try `foreach ($domains as $key) { echo $key['domain']; echo $key['status']; }`